# how do get this to work on the current viewing folder

Tags: vba, email, outlook, directory, move

I'm looking to get this to run for the current folder viewed when exploring  and not cars folder tried a few things but no success.

```vb
Public Sub Move_Inbox_Emails_From_Excel()

Dim outApp As Object
Dim outNS As Object
Dim inboxFolder As Object
Dim destFolder As Object
Dim outEmail As Object
Dim inboxItems As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim inputNumber As String
Dim numberToMove As Integer

inputNumber = InputBox("Enter number of emails to move")
On Error Resume Next
numberToMove = CInt(inputNumber)
On Error GoTo 0
If numberToMove < 1 Then Exit Sub

Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set outNS = outApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set inboxFolder = outNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set destFolder = inboxFolder.Parent.Folders("Car")             'Test folder at same level as Inbox

'Sort Inbox items by Received Time

Set inboxItems = inboxFolder.Items
'inboxItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", False     'ascending order (oldest first)
inboxItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True      'descending order (newest first)

'Loop through sorted items for the number entered by the user, up to the number of items in the Inbox

For i = inboxFolder.Items.Count To inboxFolder.Items.Count - numberToMove + 1 Step -1
Set outEmail = inboxItems(i)
'Debug.Print i, outEmail.Subject
outEmail.Move destFolder
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the line

```
Set destFolder = inboxFolder.Parent.Folders("Car")
```

with

```
Set destFolder = outApp.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
```